# Apache rails beta site access solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2

I'm building an ror site and have been asked by to put a temporary access restriction on it. All that's needed is a general access restriction to be used by beta users. The site is deployed on an apache server (on a mac) using passenger. I'm wondering what solutions there are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799641/using-htaccess-password-protection-on-rails/2802630#2802630) to this yesterday with a simple solution in Rails itself; I use this solution for protecting my development site from being spidered while testing. I've reposted it below for convenience.

---

Rails has a built-in helper for this, you could place this in your application controller:

```
protected
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "admin" && password == "test"
    end
  end
```

Then use a before_filter on any controllers you want to protect (or just stick it in the application controller to block the whole site):

```
before_filter :authenticate
```

This method works on Nginx as well as Apache, which is an added bonus. It doesn't, however, work if you have full page caching enabled - as the visitor never hits the Rails stack; it won't kick in.

**Edit**
Just noticed that you specified the /admin route. All my admin controllers inherit from an AdminController. You could set yours up like so:

/app/controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate
  protected
    def authenticate
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "admin" && password == "test"
    end
  end
end
```

Then have all your controllers extend the admin controller, eg:

```
class Admin::ThingsController < Admin::AdminController
```

My routes are setup like so:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.resources :things
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I figured there'd be something like this. I'll look into caching and give it a go ...

Comment: I've just flicked caching off for production while I'm building, but if you're doing a more serious beta test I could see that being more problematic. Good luck :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's is my first take on it, using the good old htaccess solution, which I found surprisingly little info about in regards to rails.
Generate user/password file, for user 'beta':

```
mysite> htpasswd -c .htpasswd beta
mysite> chmod 755 .htpasswd
```

Create an access configuration file in the rails public dir 'public/.htaccess', containing:

```
AuthName "Enter password"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /Users/myuser/projects/mysite/.htpasswd
require user beta
```

Change file rights:

```
mysite> chmod 755 public/.htaccess
```

Edit apache conf file (find out where it is with 'apachectl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE'). In the  section of the VirtualHost configuration, add the following to define what in the htaccess file is used:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefinery gives you an out of the box solution for this type of scenario http://www.prefinery.com/