# Rake tests all fail after htaccess implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, authentication

Thanks to [this excellent question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799641/using-htaccess-password-protection-on-rails), I have found out how I can protect my rails application by putting the following code in my application controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate

protected
def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "username" && password == "password"
    end
end
```

This all works fine, but I noticed that all tests that I wrote (which all passed) now all fail. When I comment out the before_filter call, they all pass again.

How can I go about this? Is there a way to exclude the tests from the htaccess protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your tests by including the Basic authentication, see this:

```
def test_should_get_index
  @request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
  get :index
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:articles)
end
```

Source: http://flip.netzbeben.de/2008/06/functional-test-for-http-authentication-in-rails-2/

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is there any way to tell this to all my test methods without having to write it in every single one of them?

Comment: You can include the code in the `setup` method:

`# called before every single test
  def setup
    @request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
  end`

Comment: Btw: Somehow that doesn't work in the integration tests. It gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass` - how can I fix this?

Comment: It seems that in your integration tests you do not have the `@request` variable. Try only `request` on the integration tests

Comment: Hmm... it still gives me the same error. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Try including the following `include Devise::TestHelpers`, otherwise you can try to add another param to the `get`: `:authorization => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials("username", "password") `